# How to pass a key file when spawning an ssh command from node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssh, child-process

This works from my local terminal:

```
ssh -i ~/.ec2/mykey.pem ubuntu@ec2-yada-yada.amazonaws.com ls
```

Of course it does. But when I try the same using node.js' `child_process.spawn` command it complains that the key does not exist / can't be accessed.

```
// child process
var childProcess = require('child_process').spawn;

// spawn the slave using slaveId as the key
slaves[slaveId] = childProcess('ssh', [
    '-i /mykey.pem',
    'ubuntu@ec2-yada.amazonaws.com',
    'ls'
])
```

Result:

```
stderr: Warning: Identity file  /mykey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.  
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Things tried:

1. Variations on the path to key:
   `/actual/path/to/mykey.pem`
   `mykey.pem` (with a copy of the file in the root of the node project)
   `/mykey.pem` (with a copy of the file in the root of the node project)
   `~/.ec2.mykey.pem` (where it should be)
2. Running the command without the ssh part, ie. `childProcess(ls);` - works.
3. `chmod 644, 600, 400 etc. mykey.pem`

My only theory at this point is there is an issue with passing a file reference in and I need to do *something* using the fs module. (?) And yes, I know there are libraries out there for ssh access with node but they use passwords which won't cut it and anyway, my requirements don't really justify a library.

Please tell me I'm being stupid and that this is possible.

**UPDATE:**

OK, so I *can* use the exec command like this:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process').exec;
slaves[slaveId] = childProcess('ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@ec2-yada.amazonaws.com ls',  function (error, stdout, stderr) {...}
```

Still, I feel like I've been downgraded from creating a true slave using `fork` with all it's nice messaging and handy properties (my original implementation which runs fine locally) to having a vacuum cleaner and being told to do all the work myself (now that I want to launch slaves on remote hosts).

Comment: What if you spawn with `'-i /mykey.pem'` split into two elements: `'-i', '/mykey.pem'`?

Comment: If I split it into two elements then it works. This is the solution to make spawn work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to be jumping Brandon's comments a lot lately :-). He's right again. When you execute `ssh -i ~/.ec2/mykey.pem ubuntu@ec2-yada-yada.amazonaws.com ls`, the `ssh` executable, in this case, gets four arguments: `-i`, the name of your key file, the address of the host and the command, eg. `ls -ltr /tmp`. When it sees a `-i` it expects the *next* argument to be the name of the key file, not to see the name as a trailing substring of the `-i`.

Remember that when you `spawn` a program, you invoke it directly without going through the shell, so you have to pass it exactly the arguments the shell would have passed it *after* the shell did any expansion, quoting, etc. When you use `exec`, you're actually passing a command-line string to the shell, so the shell does all that stuff for you, including figuring out where one arguments ends and another begins.

Comment: Thanks, it's odd that it __will__ accept a command such as `ls -ltr /tmp` as one argument but `-i myfile.pem` needs to be broken down into two. Pff, but it works now, as stated.