# SSH has password prompt even when I include keys in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssh

This is the code. I'm providing a key so I shouldn't need to type a password. Also, the command works on the command line.

```
var spawnArgs = [ 'ssh',
                '-nNT',
                '-L',
                localToHost,
                port,
                '-i ~/.ssh/keys',
                url]

var child = spawn('nohup', spawnArgs);
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the command in a shell ?

Comment: This seems to do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333070/how-to-pass-a-key-file-when-spawning-an-ssh-command-from-node-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a key file when spawning an ssh command from node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333070/how-to-pass-a-key-file-when-spawning-an-ssh-command-from-node-js)